# How can I access files stored in my PC from AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to access the information stored in a text file that is in my PC and display it in a ListView inside the AVD.I do no want to push the file into the avd.I want my app to access such files from a server(in this case my PC)and display the information in it.
Let's say the file is stored in C:\users.
How do I access it?

Comment: Copy th file into the emulator or into the device

Comment: Can i do it any other way instead of storing it locally?

Comment: If its a server, then you can provide ftp access to your app and read files from the server through your app. You will have to write ftp connectivity in android.

Answer (score 5):

The emulator is a separate virtual computer (usually called guest) inside your PC (host).

Guests can not access anything from the host PC directly. The only communication between both can be done via a network service.

Therefore you need on your PC a server providing a service like HTTP and on your Android emulator a client (HttpUrlConnection) that can communicate with the server and therefore get access to the file.

There are a lot of mini web servers available that allow to publish one directory of your PC.

You can access your PC and the HTTP server from within the emulator using the IP address 10.0.2.2.

Comment: I was looking for the ip 10.0.2.2. Thank you for mentioning it here